# Why won't my spotify api function properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, spotify

I am having a few issues with my page. The first issue is: the span element on my page when clicked is not doing anything. The issue I keep getting is that `element.addEventListener` is not a function. It is part of a function that is supposed to redirect me to Spotify's authorization endpoint. When I put it in the url bar manually, it works (sort of), but the button will not do anything.

Second, when I put the request for `/login` manually, it shows my access and refresh tokens in the url bar, but it is supposed to take me to an authorization page, then redirect to callback.html with those credentials. callback.js is supposed to handle those credential requests. Instead, all it does is show me my access and refresh tokens in the url bar. Here's some code. What's going on? For Issue 2, look at my project here: https://github.com/YungLonk/Spotify-API/blob/master/app.js

Issue 1 Code:

```
Issue 1 Code
// public/index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Click below to connect spotify:</h1>
        <div class="box-1">
            <div class="btn btn-one">
                <span>CONNECT SPOTIFY</span> <!-- When clicked, should redirect user to login page -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


// public/js/script.js

function login(e) { // Redirects user to login page for spotify
    if (!e) {e = window.event}
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/login', true);
    xhr.send();}
if(addEventListener) {document.getElementsByTagName('span').addEventListener('mouseup', login, false);}
else {button.mouseup(login);}
```

Comment: Just realized link doesn't work. Try this: https://github.com/YungLonk/Spotify-API/

Comment: As the name suggests, `document.getElementsByTagName('span')` returns a list of elements, not the first match. Insert `[0]` to make it work or use `document.querySelector('span')` instead.

Comment: Okay. I tried both ways, and the error disappeared. However, the button still does nothing.

Comment: Go here: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8ysfboa4/ open the console, click the `<span>`. Works fine. However: XMLHttpRequest does not send the user anywhere, it simply tries to load something from the server. If you want to navigate elsewhere, simply use `location = "/login";`

Comment: Where does the ```location = "/login"``` go? the ```xhr.send()```?

Comment: No, you can scrap the entire `xhr` code. `location` is a property of `window`, and setting it causes the browser to navigate there. You don't need anything else.

Comment: It's supposed to send a request to app2.js, which will redirect to the authorization endpoint of spotify. Also it still didn't work.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8ysfboa4/

Comment: What about my second issue described?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe spotify doesn't accept redirect URLs on `localhost`.

Comment: I just figured out that all I had to do for my second issue was add .html to my callback url.